Unresolved Reference for each call on objects in Kotlin jsr223
I am using Kotlin as a Jsr223 Scripting Engine in my Projekt. The call of a script looks like this:
val engine = ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByExtension("main.kts")!!
engine.getBindings(ScriptContext.GLOBAL_SCOPE).put("typedDocument", parameters["typedDocument"] as TypedDocument)
engine.eval(script.sourceCode)
var result = engine.eval("run()")

The engine basically works but when it comes to passing complex objects from the outside in, there is a strange quirk:
This script (executed inside the engine) works well:
fun run() {
    println(typedDocument)
}

It successfully prints the complex object to the hosts console:
TypedDocument(document=Document(id=a3eaf071-7803-4748-9dac-24e86b89767a, documentTypeId=38ca1a16-db8c-436f-af1c-a586ebe41056, values={title=New Ticket asdasd  xx, Bla=asdsd, Datum=2024-09-12, choose=Apfelsine}, actions=[ActionDescriptor(action=document.save, label={{document.save}}, defaultParameters={}, dialogDescriptor=null, level=PRIMARY), ActionDescriptor(action=document.delete, label={{document.delete}}, defaultParameters={}, dialogDescriptor=DialogDescriptor(type=CONFIRMATION, targetParameter=confirmed, parameters={title={{document.delete.confirm.title}}, message={{document.delete.confirm.message}}, level=DANGER}), level=DANGER)]), documentType=Ticket)

Now if i try to access the documentType property (which definetly exists) like this:
fun run() {
    println(typedDocument.documentType)
}

It will raise an error:
javax.script.ScriptException: ERROR Unresolved reference: documentType (ScriptingHost5a0a398_Line_0.main.kts:3:27)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.repl.KotlinJsr223JvmScriptEngineBase.asJsr223EvalResult(KotlinJsr223JvmScriptEngineBase.kt:104)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.repl.KotlinJsr223JvmScriptEngineBase.compileAndEval(KotlinJsr223JvmScriptEngineBase.kt:63)
        at kotlin.script.experimental.jvmhost.jsr223.KotlinJsr223ScriptEngineImpl.compileAndEval(KotlinJsr223ScriptEngineImpl.kt:95)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.repl.KotlinJsr223JvmScriptEngineBase.eval(KotlinJsr223JvmScriptEngineBase.kt:31)
        at java.scripting/javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(AbstractScriptEngine.java:262)
        at com.example.starter.base.core.app.controller.ScriptHostController.executeScript(ScriptHostController.kt:37)
        at com.example.starter.base.core.app.controller.actions.SaveDocumentAction.execute(SaveDocumentAction.kt:33)
        at com.example.starter.base.core.app.controller.actions.SaveDocumentAction_ClientProxy.execute(Unknown Source)
        at com.example.starter.base.core.app.controller.ActionController.callAction(ActionController.kt:19)
        at com.example.starter.base.ui.adapter.local.ActionLocalAdapter.callAction(ActionLocalAdapter.kt:14)
        at com.example.starter.base.ui.app.view.action.ActionHandler.executeAction(ActionHandler.kt:38)
        at com.example.starter.base.ui.app.view.action.ActionHandler.handleAction(ActionHandler.kt:34)
        at com.example.starter.base.ui.app.view.action.ActionHandler_ClientProxy.handleAction(Unknown Source)
        at com.example.starter.base.ui.app.view.action.ActionBar.updateActions$lambda$2$lambda$0(ActionBar.kt:49)
        at com.vaadin.flow.component.ComponentEventBus.fireEventForListener(ComponentEventBus.java:239)
        at com.vaadin.flow.component.ComponentEventBus.handleDomEvent(ComponentEventBus.java:488)
        at com.vaadin.flow.component.ComponentEventBus.lambda$addDomTrigger$dd1b7957$1(ComponentEventBus.java:298)
        at com.vaadin.flow.internal.nodefeature.ElementListenerMap.lambda$fireEvent$2(ElementListenerMap.java:447)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
        at com.vaadin.flow.internal.nodefeature.ElementListenerMap.fireEvent(ElementListenerMap.java:447)
        at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.rpc.EventRpcHandler.handleNode(EventRpcHandler.java:62)
        at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.rpc.AbstractRpcInvocationHandler.handle(AbstractRpcInvocationHandler.java:74)
        at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocationData(ServerRpcHandler.java:466)
        at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.lambda$handleInvocations$4(ServerRpcHandler.java:447)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
        at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocations(ServerRpcHandler.java:447)
        at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleRpc(ServerRpcHandler.java:324)
        at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UidlRequestHandler.java:114)
        at com.vaadin.flow.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:40)
        at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1574)
        at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:398)
        at com.vaadin.quarkus.QuarkusVaadinServlet.service(QuarkusVaadinServlet.java:84)
        at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:614)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:63)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:67)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:133)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:65)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:247)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:56)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:111)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:108)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
        at io.quarkus.undertow.runtime.UndertowDeploymentRecorder$9$1.call(UndertowDeploymentRecorder.java:626)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:227)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:152)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.CanonicalPathHandler.handleRequest(CanonicalPathHandler.java:49)
        at io.quarkus.undertow.runtime.UndertowDeploymentRecorder$1.handleRequest(UndertowDeploymentRecorder.java:125)
        at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:284)
        at io.undertow.server.DefaultExchangeHandler.handle(DefaultExchangeHandler.java:18)
        at io.quarkus.undertow.runtime.UndertowDeploymentRecorder$5$2.run(UndertowDeploymentRecorder.java:441)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxCoreRecorder$14.runWith(VertxCoreRecorder.java:582)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2513)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1538)
        at org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable.run(DelegatingRunnable.java:29)
        at org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.run(ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.java:29)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)

Every call to the object fails the same way, except the calls to methods of Object. For example the following also works well:
fun run() {
    println(typedDocument.hashCode())
}

Any Ideas? The documentation on this feature and reference implementations are very rare. So rare that even AI is useless :-)

I cannot reproduce in a fresh project. Please show a [mcve].

I can also not reproduce it in a fresh project yet. That certainly means it has to do with other components used. It is a quarkus project currently run in dev mode and the problem is related to classes so it might have to do with the Quarkus Runtime Classloader, i'll try harder to find out which dependency causes the issue.
Also for hot Code Reloading the Jetbrains Runtime JDK is used another possible source of this issue.

Meanwhile i tried a different approach not using the jsr223 interface but using the kotlin scritping host directly and it yielded the exact same results, so i created a ticket at the quarkus project and also a minimal reproducible example in that ticket:
https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/43271#issuecomment-2349405532
It also contains a working version without quarkus being startet.
